# Django: add localhost deployment to CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS

Tags: django

I am trying to debug my cloud deployed Django app. I want to make request to the app using my locally deployed frontend app. I have made the `localhost` and `localhost:3000` to trusted origins.

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost',
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'https://example.com',
]
```

In my Django app, I still get

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

How can I add my local frontend deployment to `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS`? Should it be my external IP Address?

What is the other way to debug this way and exempting my localhost frontend to the CSRF verification?

Comment: tried? `from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
` if its fine to exempt.

Comment: How can I add a REST framework view? Should I only exempt login and logout? It says its not recommended.

Comment: yeah for login should not use `csrf_exempt`

Answer (score 0):

Install the cors-header package.

https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

In the app list:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders",
    ...,
]
```

In the middleware, please add it.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    ...,
]
```

Comment: I have this already in my project.

Comment: @Nikko, You installed the corsheaders package and set it in settings.py file according to the : https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/    ?

Comment: Yes, I have set the `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS ` and still get the error.

Comment: @Nikko, You need to add the package name in `INSTALLED_APPS = []
` and middleware `MIDDLEWARE = [` also.

Comment: As mentioned, I have those in my settings. But still it does not work since I get the `CSRF verification` error.

Comment: `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost',
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'https://example.com',
]`   Where is your cloud hosted domain name in the list?